# extract tags from soup with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

[image]

```
'''
<div class="kt-post-card__body>
<div class="kt-post-card__title">Example_1</div>
<div class="kt-post-card__description">Example_2</div>
<div class="kt-post-card__bottom">
<span class="kt-post-card__bottom-description kt-text-truncate" title="Example_3">Example_4</span>
</div>
</div>
'''
```

according to picture I attached, I want to extract all "kt-post-card__body" attrs and then from each one of them, extract:

```
("kt-post-card__title", "kt-post-card__description")
```

like a list.

I tried this:

```
ads = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'kt-post-card__body'})
```

but with `ads[0].div` I only access to `"kt-post-card__title"` while `"kt-post-card__body"` has three other sub tags like: `"kt-post-card__description"` and `"kt-post-card__bottom"` ... , why is that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you shows HTML from browser but first you should see what HTML you get in your code. Many pages use JavaScript to add elements but `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript  - so it may not find some elements.

Comment: maybe you should use another `find_all()` to search inside this part - `ads[0].find_all('div')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause your question is not that clear - To extract the classes:

```
for e in soup.select('.kt-post-card__body'):
    print([c for t in e.find_all() for c in t.get('class')])
```

Output:

```
['kt-post-card__title', 'kt-post-card__description', 'kt-post-card__bottom', 'kt-post-card__bottom-description', 'kt-text-truncate']
```

---

To get the texts you also have to iterate your `ResultSet` and could access each elements text to fill your list or use `stripped_strings`.

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc='''
<div class="kt-post-card__body">
<div class="kt-post-card__title">Example_1</div>
<div class="kt-post-card__description">Example_2</div>
<div class="kt-post-card__bottom">
<span class="kt-post-card__bottom-description kt-text-truncate" title="Example_3">Example_4</span>
</div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

for e in soup.select('.kt-post-card__body'):
    data = [
        e.select_one('.kt-post-card__title').text,
        e.select_one('.kt-post-card__description').text      
    ]
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
['Example_1', 'Example_2']
```

or

```
print(list(e.stripped_strings))
```

Output:

```
['Example_1', 'Example_2', 'Example_4']
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want and work great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ads = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'kt-post-card__body'})

ads[0]
```

I think you're getting only the first div because you called `ads[0].div`